# JSLint and undefined functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I'd love to live in a lint free world. JSLint that is. But I'm having some problems that I'm not sure I should ignore or fix. Specifically I'm getting a number of:

```
[functionName] not defined
```

errors. I do recognise that you should always define the function before using it and I assume that's what the message is really warning against but here are two cases where I think there is a valid exception:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   // code goes here
}
```

In a simple file which starts with a typical noconflict wrapper for jQuery I get a warning saying that "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {" is not defined. Obviously jQuery is defined in a separate file that needs to stay separate. Does that make sense?

The second example is really quite similar although arguably it is more avoidable. In this case I have two JS files in my project. One that looks just like the one above (aka, it's a set of DOM triggered events wrapped inside of jQuery's "ready" event). The other has a number of helper functions that look like this:

```
function doSomethingImportant() { };
function doSomethingImpressive() { };
```

These functions are then called within the first JS file. JSLint doesn't like this and complains every time the first JS file calls a function defined in the second JS file: doSomethingImportant() { is not defined. Yet in reality, since the functions are defined at load time and the calls to those functions always happen afterward based on DOM events there never seems to be a real problem.

Anyway, open to ideas. Is this a case of filtering JSLint's advice or something I should fix in code?

Comment: look at the bottom of the page, there is an input field with *predefine global variables here*. Just add all globals without commas there, e.g. `jQuery doSomethingImportant doSomethingImpressive`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting these errors because JSLint assumes that at some point in the future you might do:

```
var doSomethingImpressive = function() { }
```

in which case you would get an error, because the file where the function is defined is included after the function call (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname))

The same goes for the jQuery call. You can either change the order of your scripts, or safely ignore the errors.